# Whats the difference between .call.value() and .call.value()()

Tags: solidity

```
contract Test {

    function Test(){
        msg.sender.call.value(0);
        msg.sender.call.value(0)();
    }

}
```

Whats the difference here between the first and second call? My hunch is the 1st one doesn't actually do anything, however this indeed does compile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first should not do anything because the call function is not invoked. You just set the value that you want to send with the `call` but then don't invoke it. It is explained [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.5/frequently-asked-questions.html):

> Every external function call in Solidity can be modified in two ways:
>
> 1. You can add Ether together with the call
> 2. You can limit the amount of gas available to the call

Answer (score 6):

From: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.11/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do

> What does `p.recipient.call.value(p.amount)(p.data)` do? Every external
> function call in Solidity can be modified in two ways:
>
> You can add Ether together with the call You can limit the amount of
> gas available to the call This is done by “calling a function on the
> function”:
>
> `f.gas(2).value(20)()` calls the modified function `f` and thereby sending
> 20 Wei and limiting the gas to 2 (so this function call will most
> likely go out of gas and return your 20 Wei).
>
> In the above example, the low-level function `call` is used to invoke
> another contract with `p.data` as payload and `p.amount` Wei is sent with
> that call.