# Calling function from deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, addresses, function-selector

I want to know how to instantiate an **existing contract deployed on the blockchain** using its address.
e.g:

```
contract A {
    function f1()
    {}
}
```

`A` is deployed on the blockchain, and in contract `B` I want to call the function `f1()` and get its return.
e.g:

```
contract B {
    address contrac_A=0x123456;

    //call f1 from A
}
```

How should I call it using the address of `A`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the deployed contract doesn’t adhere to the ABI, but you know the contract signature (name and argument types) You could use :

```
contract_address.call(bytes4(sha3("function_name(types)")),parameters_values)
```

for example : `contrac_A.call(bytes4(sha3("f()"))` while there is no input no parameters in your exemple.

replace contract_address,function_name,parameters_values by your credentials.

**Edit :**
as sha3 has been deprecated it's better to use instead keccak256 as following: `bytes4(keccak256("f()")).`

Furthermore, since solidity 0.4.22, the global functions `abi.encode(), abi.encodePacked(), abi.encodeWithSelector() and abi.encodeWithSignature()` have been defined to encode structured data and therefore helping us to build valid call (they return the needed 4 bytes) as follow :

```
contract_address.call.value(1 ether).gas(10)(abi.encodeWithSignature("register(string)", "MyName"));
```

**Documentation**:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#generic-call-method

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#function-selector

Comment: I have seen a function as follows.                                                                                           function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data, string _custom_fallback) returns (bool success) {
      
    
        ContractReceiver receiver = ContractReceiver(_to);
        receiver.call.value(0)(bytes4(sha3(_custom_fallback)), msg.sender, _value, _data);
        return true;
    }        .....What's the use of value(0) here??

Comment: f.call.value(X) is calling f with X wei check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/whats-the-difference-between-call-value-and-call-value

Answer (score 27):

### Use an abstract contract (preferred)

Further clarifications to @Edmund's answer:

```
contract A { // This doesn't have to match the real contract name. Call it what you like.
   function f1(bool arg1, uint arg2) returns(uint); // No implementation, just the function signature. This is just so Solidity can work out how to call it.
}

contract YourContract {
  function doYourThing(address addressOfA) returns(uint) {
    A my_a = A(addressOfA);
    return my_a.f1(true, 3);
  }
}
```

This shows using the return value from `f1`.

Also, if `f1` encounters an exception (imagine its implementation is `function f1(bool arg1, uint arg2) returns(uint) { throw; }`), the exception is propagated and `my_a.f1` will also `throw` and it will revert a transaction that invoked `doYourThing`.

In practice, you'll have 3 files.

AbstractA.sol contains:

```
contract A {
   function f1(bool arg1, uint arg2) returns(uint); // No implementation, just the function signature. This is just so Solidity can work out how to call it.
}
```

YourContract.sol contains:

```
import "AbstractA.sol"

contract YourContract {
  function doYourThing(address addressOfA) returns(uint) {
    A my_a = A(addressOfA);
    return my_a.f1(true, 3);
  }
}
```

A.sol contains:

```
contract A {
   // implementation of f1
   function f1(bool arg1, uint arg2) returns(uint) {
       if (arg1) {
           throw;
       } else {
           return arg2;
       }
   }
}
```

### Limitations of using `call`

`call` is suggested in @Badr's answer but should be used very carefully.  [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html) state:

> All three functions `call`, `delegatecall` and `callcode` are very
>   low-level functions and should only be used as a last resort as they
>   break the type-safety of Solidity.

Also, the return value of `f1` can't be obtained by using `call` like `addressOfA.call(bytes4(keccak256("f1(bool, uint256)")), true, 3)` because `call` only returns a `bool` (`false` if the call encounters an exception).

This means that the exception must be propagated manually like:

```
if (!addressOfA.call(bytes4(keccak256("f1(bool, uint256)")), true, 3)) {
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Do we have to include visibility and modifiers when specifying the function signature?

Comment: @DigitalJedi Yes, there have been improvements to Solidity since 2017, and they include being explicit about visibility.

Answer (score 4):

```
contract A { // This doesn't have to match the real contract name. Call it what you like.
   function f1(){} // No implementation, just the function signature. This is just so Solidity can work out how to call it.
}

contract YourContract 
  function doYourThing() {
    A my_a = A(contract_A);
    my_a.f1();
  }
}
```

Comment: they are not in the same contract file  the compiler will not recongnise the contract A so no A my_a = A(contract_A);

Comment: Put them in the same file. You don't need the full implementation, just the function signatures.

Comment: I am asking about an alredy deployed contract.

Comment: You don't need the full source code. You must know the name of the method you're calling and what parameters it takes, so stick that in a contract definition called A, leave the function body empty and plonk it above the contract that's going to call it.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide context. That really is all you need, it doesn't matter whether the contract is already deployed or not. If your original code won't compile, check the spelling of "function".

Comment: @EdmundEdgar   I have seen a function as follows.                                                                                           function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data, string _custom_fallback) returns (bool success) {
      
    
        ContractReceiver receiver = ContractReceiver(_to);
        receiver.call.value(0)(bytes4(sha3(_custom_fallback)), msg.sender, _value, _data);
        return true;
    }        .....What's the use of value(0) here??

Comment: This should be the case. Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solidity code for the **New contract** that can call the f1() function from your **Old contract**. Hope this helps. I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

```
    import "./Old.sol";    // You import the existing contract. 
        
        
            /**
            * The NEW contract will call the Old one
            */
        
          contract New {
          
               Old OLD; // Intitilize old contract variable (empty)
        
            /**
             * Set the address for Old contract (We call this function and enter the address of the OLD contract)
             */
            function setOldContractAddress(address addr) public {
                OLD = Old(addr);
            }
        
        
             /**
             * Function that allows us to call f1() from the Old contract
             */
            function callOLDcontract() public {
                OLD.f1();
             
                }
            
            }
```