# how to import an already deployed contract into my contract

Tags: solidity

I have two smart contracts, 
  the first which i intend to deploy first then after a couple of days the other will follow. my issue is how to import this contract i have already deployed and use its functions in my contract.
i have tried
`Coin1 _coin1 = Coin1(addressOfCoin1);` 
 but it doesn't work and when i use the import statement it throws error at point of deployment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling function from deployed contract](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract)

Comment: Upvoted even though I agree duplicate and added more helpful information on Sig's question, such as coderwithattitude question about specifying all arguments in the abstract contract; and an example of 3 files showing the abstract contract, the implementation, and the "caller".

Answer (score 6):

in the same file define the first contract in an abstract form and within your current contract make the needed call,e.g:

```
 contract Coin1{
        function f() payable returns (uint);
    }


    contract Coin2{
        Coin1 coin;
        function setcoin(address addr) { coin= Coin1(addr); }
        function callcoin() { coin.f.value(10).gas(800)(); // you call the desired function here we call info with 800 gas; }
    }
```

you will find more detail on the official [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=extends#external-function-calls) about the External Function Calls

Comment: Thank you for your response but when i do this i get the following error "member not found in argument dependent lookup" do i need to specify all the arguments in the live contract in the abstract form also?

Comment: and the constructor in coin gives me error "non empty returns directive"

Comment: @coderwithattitude Yes, you need to specify all arguments in the abstract form.  Constructors don't return values so remove the returns in your constructor to fix it.

Comment: thanks for your time, this is what worked for me incase anyone needs it. https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/interactions-between-contracts/