# Import a contract hosted on a testnet from it's address

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, inheritance

I have a smart contract that imports another, and I'm wondering how to deploy them to a testnet.

Right now, one contract imports the other locally;

```
import "./firstContract.sol"

contract secondContract is firstContract {
...
}
```

What would I chance the `import "./firstContract.sol"` line to once the first contract is deployed to a testnet via remix, and I want to deploy the second contract?

[I found some documentation on it](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_import.html) but it doesn't quite have what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand inheritance.

In this arrangement, the source code of `firstContract.sol` is rolled up and included in `secondContract.sol`. You deploy `secondContract`. The end.

Communication with another deployed contract is a separate concept that would not include `is DeployedContract`. Have a look at this for a concise example of how that would work in case it's closer to what you have in mind. [Creating a function that calls another contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44383/creating-a-function-that-calls-another-contract)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was able to figure out what I wanted to do with the help of your answer. What I was looking to do was have the second contract inherit the first one, then I just needed to deploy the second contract.