# With TRUFFLE: Call public function of contract from within another contract

Tags: truffle

Similar to [How do you call a function of a deployed contract from another contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17401/how-do-you-call-a-function-of-a-deployed-contract-from-another-contract) (first answer), but because Truffle has access to the ABI's of compiled contracts thought I could avoid low-level `call`

Want to call a public function `timeProtectTokens` on `token` variable representing ERC20 contract within Escrow contract.
Intuitively I thought to do:

```
 let token = await ERC20.new()
 let escrow = await Escrow.new(token.address)
 let result = await escrow.token.timeProtectTokens(initialAccount, 5)
```

*..but fails*

```
contract ERC20 is Protected {
}

import "./ERC20.sol";                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

contract Escrow {
  ERC20 public token;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  constructor(ERC20 _token) public {
    token = _token;
  }
}

contract Protected {
  mapping (address => uint256) public protectedTokens;                                                                                                                                                                                       

  function timeProtectTokens(address _address, uint256 _amount) public **onlyEscrow** {
    protectedTokens[_address] = protectedTokens[_address].add(_amount);                                                                                                                                                                     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way.

First, you need to do `const tokenAddress = await escrow.token();`.

Then, you need to use this address in order to create a contract object.

If you're on Truffle v4.x (web3.js v0.x), then you can do:

```
const tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(<Your ERC20 ABI Array>).at(tokenAddress);
```

If you're on Truffle v5.x (web3.js v1.x), then you can do:

```
const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(<Your ERC20 ABI Array>, tokenAddress);
```

But I believe that you might experience problems interacting with your contract within Truffle tests.

So alternatively, you should probably use [@truffle/contract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract).

Following that, you should finally be able to do:

```
const result = await tokenContract.timeProtectTokens(initialAccount, 5);
```

Comment: Syntax I'm using (ie ERC20.new()) is truffle-contract... 
I'd prefer to use truffle-contract because this for a test issue (timeProtectTokens uses OZ's Roles contract modifier, requiring that the call originate from the Escrow Contract, not a user account )

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name: What is `ERC20` in your Truffle test?