# How can a deployed contract call another deployed contract by _interface_ and address?

Tags: solidity

There is a nice article about writing upgradable Solidity code [article about writing upgradable Solidity code](https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88)

The question is however (*ref the article*) if ITokenLedger is intentionally "contract" and not "interface"? Can ITokenLedger be "interface" and how this will affect the implementation of the calling "contract"?

What are the recommended methods of calling "contract" within another "contract" provided caller is only aware of the **callee's** ABI and address, with respect to *gas* consumption?

While this is most likely an noob question I appreciate your patience and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended method would be employing abstract contract (or interface) definition in solidity code (see *Service.sol*) and the address of the deployed contract implementing it.

**Example**

Deployed **Service.sol**:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Service{

  function isAlive() public constant returns(bool alive) {
    // do something
    return true;
  }
}
```

Let's assume the deployed contract is deployed at `0x123...` (see serviceAddress below).

Now we want to describe a contract that will use it for something. We'll describe the *abstract contract* only, so the client knows how to communicate. Then we'll pass in the address so it knows what to communicate with.

**Client.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

// describe the interface

contract Service{
  function isAlive() constant returns(bool alive) {} // empty because we're not concerned with internal details
}

contract Client {
  Service _s; // "Service" is a Type and the compiler can "see" it because this is one file. 

  function Client(address serviceAddress) {
    _s = Service(serviceAddress); // _s will be the "Service" located at serviceAddress
  }

  function Ping() public constant returns(bool response) {
    return _s.isAlive(); // message/response to Service is intuitive
  }
}
```

Calling deployed contract by ABI and address is similar to a reflection call (expensive) with the limitation that the only output from the call is a boolean return value designating success (true) or an exception (false).

Comment: Thank you for prompt response! Would you be able to validate the following two statements:
1. Both, _interface_ and _abstract contract_ will generate ABI which is exactly the same and does exactly correspond to the ABI of the contract implementing either or both.
2. Compiler does not produce byte-code neither for _interface_ (my question) nor for _abstract contract_ (your example). This makes it impossible to deploy and hence does not employ blockchain as a "publication/distribution mechanism". It is only possible to deploy  bytecode generated from a _contract_ or a _library_.

Comment: If the above two statements validate *true* then:

Q1. The only way of distributing _interface_ or _abstract contract_ and not compromise type safety is to share their solidity code? 
Q1.1 Or is there a way to generate solidity code for these off the ABI? (Aka WCF client generation off WSDL)

Comment: Is ABI and address of the deployed contract enough:
A. to call the contract from another contract.
B. to make a transaction from an external account.

Q2 What are the best practices for use case (A) and (B) provided one only knows the ABI and the address.
Q2.1 Is it correct that in case of contract invokation by only ABI + address the type safety is not employed? (Aka invokation via reflection)

Comment: I just found a relevant question with good answers: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract. It discusses recommended  calling method which is the same as the one @Rob_Hitchens and the article by Elena_Dimitrova from Coloni in the original question describes.

Comment: More on the subject: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-is-the-low-level-function-call-less-favorable-than-instantiating-a-contract-with-a-variable-contractb-b-and-executing-its-functions-b-dosomething

Comment: it's generally polite and necessary to disclose both the address and the ABI to others who will want to use the contract. The ABI is given by the compiler but it isn't published on the chain. It's a real challenge to delimit fields (and more) if/when the ABI is unknown.