# How do I watch Events from multiple contracts

Tags: events

I wrote a script that is able to read events from one contract address and then paste it into a .csv. Now I would like to extend that script listening watching/reading the same event of several contracts but which are just executing activities from the "main" contract" via calls. These contracts are also created by the "main contract".

Right now I am using:

```
var instance = web3.eth.contract
var mycontract = instance.at
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this, but instead of using your own contract, you'll need to import the contract from the ethereum blockchain.
[Interaction between contracts](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/interactions-between-contracts/)

You can also call the methods from another smart contract, this thread has a very useful answer, and i think is what you're looking for:
[Calling function from deployed contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract)