# Calling a function in external contract: "type bool is not implicitly convertible to uint256"

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I have an ERC20 token contract (say at address `0x0a6ebb3690b7983e470D3aBFB86636cf64925B98`) with the `totalSupply()` function:

```
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256) {
           return _totalSupply;
}
```

I want to call this function from another contract and assign the value of `_totalSupply` that is returned to a `totalSupplyTest` variable, eg:

```
uint256 public totalSupplyTest

totalSupplyTest = 0x0a6ebb3690b7983e470D3aBFB86636cf64925B98.call(bytes4(keccak256("totalSupply(uint256)")),"");
```

This results in the error:

> Type bool is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256

There must be something wrong in the syntax I am using - in this case how should the `totalSupply()` function in the external contract be called?

Comment: per https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract `call` only returns a bool; how should this be done (or can it be done) to return a value of a uint256 type from another contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From solidity you can't obtain the returned value of a call (or delegatecall) they are low level interfaces that only return a boolean indicating if the call was successful or not.

You have to define an interface a make the call through it

```
interface MyToken {
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256);
}
```

Now you can cast the address to the interface and make the call normaly

```
function Test() public {
    uint256 public totalSupplyTest;
    address myAddress = 0x0a6ebb3690b7983e470D3aBFB86636cf64925B98;

    totalSupplyTest = MyToken(myAddress).totalSupply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`call` returns a `bool` indicating if the call was correctly formed. You have to query the result from the callback.

So, in e.g. web3:

```
contract.totalSupply.call().then(res => console.log(res))
```