# Can i use a contract which is deployed

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20, dapps

I just have a question in my mind. can I use the contracts which are already deployed so that I can use them without even myself have to deploy it again.

For example, take SafeMath I think I would have been deployed already on the network.how can I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Any deployed contract is usable by invoking its public methods. Some contract method invocation maybe restricted using specific addresses (ex :onlyOwner modifiers).

To use a contract, you need to have their address :

```
address.call(bytes4(keccak256("MethodName(arguments)")),argumentsValue)
```

You should also check this answer for better understanding : 
[Calling function from deployed contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you know the address and the function is public, anyone can call it.