# Calling deployed contract with calldata and without interface

Tags: solidity, calldata

I want to call the Seaport contract ([SeaportContract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581)), more precisely the `fulfillBasicOrder` function but I have some problems.
First I know that in order to call another function contract we need to have its interface, problem: the Seaport interface needs many additional files to be imported and I wondered if there was maybe another way to call it so Ive seen here [Calling function from deployed contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract)

And now my other problem is that, I indeed have the function signature `("fulfillBasicOrder((address,uint256,uint256,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint8,uint256,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,bytes32,uint256,(uint256,address)[],bytes))")`
But I only have the calldata to call it, no parameters (so some very long string bytes `0xfb0f3ee1000000000.....0000000000000000`). Is there a way I can call that function the way I described ? So without using interface and with the calldata ? Or will I have to import manually all of the seaport files.

Comment: You could create your own interface with just the functions you need instead. Alternatively you can use ethers to perform a low level call https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-call

Comment: Thats what I did for the interface, but I have problem fulfilling the function

Comment: You could use the `interface.encodeFunctionData` function (see ethers docs) to encode the parameters. Or when you start with the calldata you can decode it via `interface.decodeFunctionData`.

Comment: The problem is that Im trying to do all of that on chain @MarkusSchick

Comment: Similar functions are available in solidity. https://solidity-by-example.org/call/, https://solidity-by-example.org/abi-encode/, https://solidity-by-example.org/abi-decode/

Answer (score 2):

Define interface like this

```
interface ISeaPort{
// whatever the function is 
}
```

And call the function in your contract like this.

```
Iseaport(addressOfSeaportCotract).Functionname(Function Arguments);
```