# What does the assert() indicate here?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-223

Here is code snippet,

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data, string memory _custom_fallback) public returns (bool success) {

   if(isContract(_to)) {
       if (balanceOf(msg.sender) < _value) revert();
       balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balanceOf(msg.sender), _value);
       balances[_to] = safeAdd(balanceOf(_to), _value);
       assert(_to.call.value(0)(bytes4(keccak256(_custom_fallback)), msg.sender, _value, _data));
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    return true;
   }
   else {
       return transferToAddress(_to, _value, _data);
   }
}
```

I am currently working with `Solidity Version ^0.5.1`. What is the alternative and upgraded method to execute this assert function given below. And what is the main working of this `assert()` and their arguments?

> assert(_to.call.value(0)(bytes4(keccak256(_custom_fallback)), msg.sender, _value, _data));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> assert(_to.call.value(0)(bytes4(keccak256(_custom_fallback)),
>   msg.sender, _value, _data));

- **what is the main working of this assert() and their arguments?**

This `assert` is calling a function of `_to` (when it is a contract) passed as a parameter in `transfer` and checking the return value as true. `bytes4(keccak256(_custom_fallback))` is used to select the function to execute and `msg.sender, _value, _data` are the parameter values to pass in calling function. `value(0)` signifies the sending of 0 wei with the call.

See related: [Whats the difference between .call.value() and .call.value()()](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/whats-the-difference-between-call-value-and-call-value)

- **What is the alternative and upgraded method to execute this assert
  function given below**

You can use `abi.encodeWithSignature(string memory signature, ...) returns (bytes memory)` as:

> _to.call.value(0)(abi.encodeWithSignature(_custom_fallback, msg.sender, _value, _data));

See related: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions

Comment: But Right now I am working with ERC223 token transfer, in that case does Signature Encoding is really applicable? Previously I have used keccak256(abi.encodePacked()) for this encoding. But there is wrong syntax or structure I have, so It didn't worked with _to.call.value(0).