# Parameters that can be passed in curly braces for message call and delegate call

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether

When I use "call" in solidity I am able to pass parameters in parenthesis and in curly braces.

- What is the full list of parameters I can pass in curly braces?
- What is the main difference between {} and ()? What kind of data do I need to pass to -> (), and -> {}

`someContract.call{value: msg.value}(data)`

Comment: See this thread: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/whats-the-difference-between-call-value-and-call-value